# Logical error in a program that computes the sum of all values (that are between L and R) of the nodes in a tree

Tags: tree, sum, binary-tree, nodes, root

can someone tell me the logical error in my program,  I tried to solve it on Leetcode, but when the input is [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15. It computes only the first value, which is 10.
The goal is to add all values that are between L and R (inclusive)

```
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    static int sum  ;
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        sum = 0 ;
        AddThem(root , L , R) ;
        return sum ;
    }
    public static int AddThem(TreeNode root , int L , int R){
        if(root==null)
            return 0 ;
        if(root.val<=R && root.val>=L){
            sum += root.val ;
        }
        sum += AddThem(root.left , L, R); 
        sum  += AddThem(root.right , L , R);
        return 0 ; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
        if(root.val<=R && root.val>=L){
            sum += root.val ;
        }
```

might be in an incorrect order:

```
class Solution {
    static int sum  ;
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0 ;
        }

        sum = 0 ;
        AddThem(root , L , R) ;
        return sum ;
    }

    public static int AddThem(TreeNode node, int L , int R) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            AddThem(node.left , L, R);
        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            AddThem(node.right , L , R);
        }

        if (node.val >= L && node.val <= R) {
            sum += node.val ;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This'd pass:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final int rangeSumBST(
        final TreeNode root,
        final int L,
        final int R
    ) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int sum = 0;

        if (root.val > L) {
            sum += rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R);
        }

        if (root.val < R) {
            sum += rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R);
        }

        if (root.val >= L && root.val <= R) {
            sum += root.val;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the tree is:

```
       10
  5          15
3   7      n    18
```

When you call `sum += AddThem(root.left , L, R);`, the root is `5` which is less than `L = 7`, so the condition `root.val<=R && root.val>=L` is false (`5 < L = 7`). Therefore, the result is not correct.